# Chart.js: Is it able to connect two points of data where there are no data between them?

Tags: chart.js, linechart

Let me ask a general question about Chart.js.

Is it able to connect two points of data where there are no data between them?

Image of Chart.js line chart:
[image: image of Chart.js line chart]

In this case, I would like to connect data of "2017/11" with "2018/02" which have data entry, keeping labels remained for no data entry months and not showing data for them(2017/12 and 2018/01).

As far as I could see the specification, it seems to be difficult, but if possible, I wanna see how I could do that.

Thank you for your advice in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a clue to make it happen.

spanGaps: boolean worked for me.